# TOC with only appendix (A,B) not sections (A.1)

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have a table of contents which has the chapters as:

1. Chapter 1...............1 
1.1 section 1..............1 
1.1.1 Subsection 1.....1 
2. Chapter 2...............2 
etc.. 
Appendix...................12 
A. Demostrations.......13 
A.1 1º Demostration .12 
B. Results...................13 
B.1 1º result

But what I want is that the TOC in the appendix only goes to the subsection as follows:

1. Chapter 1...............1 
1.1 section 1..............1 
1.1.1 Subsection 1.....1 
2. Chapter 2...............2 
etc.. 
Appendix...................12 
A. Demostrations.......13 
B. Results...................13

My code is the following, I have not include the content as it is not necesary and to not make a huge question.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\setcounter{section}{-1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\usebetterlinkanchor}[1]{%
  \gdef\Hy@chapapp{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\compconj}[1]{%
  \overline{#1}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Miguel Sanz Narrillos}
\lhead{Apuntes procesamiento de señales aleatorias}
%\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{18/04/2018}
\title{Apuntes procesamiento de señales aleatorias}
\author{Miguel Sanz Narrillos}
\date{Finalizado en : \today}


\begin{document}


\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\include{01-Estimacion_lineal}
\include{02-Estimacion_lineal_iterativa}
\include{03-Prediccion_lineal_e_interpolacion_lineal}
\include{04-Filtro_de_Wiener}
\include{05-Aplicacion_del_filtro_de_Wiener_en_prediccion_interpolacion_y_ecualizacion}

\include{06-appendix}

\end{document}
```

The appendix structure is the following:

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Demostraciones:}

\lfoot{}
\section{Demostración 1}\label{eqn:demostracion_1}



\section{Demostración 2}\label{eqn:demostracion_2}



\section{Demostración 3}\label{eqn:demostracion_3}


\end{appendices}
```

Comment: By saying  'I have not include the content as it is not necesary and to not make a huge question.' you have effectively posted a document,that does not really generate a ToC at all... We're not seeing how you generate the appendix -- is it `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}` or with `\begin{subappendices}...\end{appendices}`? Basically it could be very simple by changing `\thesection` etc. for the appendix, but again... we see no code and can guess only!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks I have added the appendix structure, when I said the content I was referering to the content of each section, I should add the structure of the appendix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change `tocdepth` for the appendices:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\apptocmd\appendices
  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begingroup\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}}
  {}{\appendicesPatchFailed}
\apptocmd\endappendices
  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}}
  {}{\appendicesPatchFailed}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\apptocmd\appendices
  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begingroup\protect\value{tocdepth}=0}}
  {}{\appendicesPatchFailed}
\apptocmd\endappendices
  {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\endgroup}}
  {}{\appendicesPatchFailed}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\begin{appendices}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]